# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw flag1 at the location stored in positions however, their values are not stored as integers or floats and I receive the following error:

```
    return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

I  am wondering how to convert the values  of the following list to floats so that I can draw at their cords:

```
        positions = [
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'A', 7],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'G', 7],
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'A', 1],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'G', 1]
]

occupied = [  # To store the grid occupied
    [('A', 7)],
    [('G', 7)],
    [('A', 1)],
    [('G', 1)]
]
```

The draw function being called:

```
    turtle.setpos(positions[0][:2]) #MAKE A = 1 
turtle.write('ABC', align='center', font=20)
turtle.dot(20, "blue")
occupied[0].append((positions[0][2], positions[0][3]))
flag1((positions[0][2], positions[0][3]))
```

The draw function:

```
def flag1(x,y):
penup()
color("black")
fillcolor("white")
seth(90)

bg_blue = ('blue')
bg_red = ('red')

goto(x, y)
fillcolor("white")
seth(90)
begin_fill()
forward(90 - 4)
right(90)
forward(120 - 4)
right(90)
forward(90 - 4)
right(90)
forward(120 - 4)
right(90)
end_fill()
goto(x, y)
```

Comment: Is `HORIZONTAL` a string?

Comment: horizontal is the width of the grid that I need to draw in VERTICAL = 90
HORIZONTAL = 120

Comment: You're passing strings to `flag1` and `goto(x, y)` is failing

Comment: how can i  convert the strings to a float value

Comment: You're passing the wrong list indexes. When you call `flag1`, use this: `flag1(positions[0][0], positions[0][1])`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thanks mike I was able to sort it out with your notes you can change to answer if you want I will approve and upvote. cheers